# Reporting API via APEX: Get Instances

Tags: apex, reporting, controller, visualforce-component

I was under the impression that when I `runReport()` using the `ReportManager` class that a rolling 24 hour instance would be cached so that if I need the data in a subsequent call I would not need to rerun the report. But now as I am implementing my framework I'm not finding a method to get the instance ID that I was expecting.

Is this something only available through the REST API?

At the moment I'm attempting something like:

```
Reports.ReportResults Reports.ReportManager.runReport(reportId);
```

Thinking then that I could do something like `data.getId()` or `data.getInstanceId();` but those aren't methods of the `ReportResults` class.

> **EDIT:**
>   I've since learned that I need to use **`Reports.ReportManager.runAsyncReport()`** in order to get a **`Reports.ReportInstance`** so that I can use the `getId()`

Now that I've fixed the syntax issue I'm not sure how to get the report that I need when I need it. Before using `runReport()` I had the results readily available but now using an async method I have to check the status like so:

```
public static Reports.ReportResults processInstance(Reports.ReportInstance reportInstance) {        
    if (reportInstance.getStatus() != 'Running' && reportInstance.getStatus() != 'New') {
        return reportInstance.getReportResults();
    } else {           
        // This does not work: causes Maximum stack depth reached: 1001 error
        return processInstance(reportInstance);
    }
}
```

Since I cannot use my `else` statement above, and basically the report is never going to be ready on page load (visualforce page), so how do I get the results that I need. Is this something I have to use JS/Ajax somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the "else" call is failing is because you're calling your method recursively. The final recursion (when the report Status is no longer new or running) never happens so you blow the stack.

AFAIK, there is no time to "wait" in APEX until a certain event happens (or even sleep a thread for a certain amount of time). The reason they prevent you from doing that is so that you don't lock a thread in their runtime environment.

The only way I would see to do this is to have external, non-apex code (javascript?) polling your report until it's ready, and then displaying it.

Comment: or VF actionPoller

Comment: I came to same conclusion and because `<apex:poller>` has a minimum of 5 seconds it won't work for my solution. For now running report synchronously on a scheduler and storing results in a cache object to be used at run time instead of running report at run time. Not sure how to get `String` stored back to a `Reports.ReportResults` data type though... :(

Answer (score 0):

Below is how I managed to run the reports from Apex only if they are older than 2 hours. Otherwise, I would return a cached results without running them again. This helped me make sure I wouldn't run over my limits.

```
    List<Report> reportList = [SELECT Id, DeveloperName FROM Report WHERE DeveloperName='Monthly_Usage_Report'];
    String reportId = (String) reportList.get(0).get('Id');

    //get all the cached async ReportInstances performed against this report
    List<Reports.ReportInstance> repInstances = Reports.ReportManager.getReportInstances(reportId);

    //find the latest instance
    Reports.ReportInstance latestInstance;
    for(Reports.ReportInstance instance : repInstances){
        if(instance.getStatus() == 'Success'){
            latestInstance = instance;
            break;
        }
    }

    //see if the latest instance is fresh enough
    DateTime twoHoursAgo = DateTime.now().addHours(-2);
    Reports.ReportResults rResults;
    if(latestInstance != null && latestInstance.getCompletionDate() > twoHoursAgo){
        //this is fresh
        System.debug('cached report');
        rResults = latestInstance.getReportResults();
    }else{
        //the last instance is not fresh, get the new one synchronously 
        //and run the async one so I have it cached for future calls
        System.debug('stale report, getting a fresh one');
        Reports.ReportInstance instance = Reports.ReportManager.runAsyncReport(reportId, true);     
        rResults = Reports.ReportManager.runReport(reportId, true);
    }

    //do stuff with rResults
```