# Convert String to Reports.ReportResults

Tags: apex, reports-api, caching

As I began to mention in the [comments of my previous post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/102639/10834), I trying to store the `Reports.ReportResults` data into a custom caching object. I am able to store the data by converting the results to a `String` like so:

```
Reports.ReportResults results;
String stringResults = (String) JSON.serialize(results);
```

but when it comes to retrieving the results I seem to be in a bind. I thought I could accomplish this with something like this

```
String cache = [SELECT Results__c FROM Cache__c WHERE Report_Name__c = :report LIMIT 1].Results__c;
return (Reports.ReportResults) JSON.deserialize(cache, Reports.ReportResults.class);
```

But unfortunately that returns me with this fatal error:

```
FATAL_ERROR|System.JSONException: Apex Type unsupported in JSON: Object
```

Any ideas on if this is even possible or should I be working on a totally different approach? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have access to [Platform Cache](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/05/platform-cache.html)? JSON does have some limitations, but I think the cache might work.

Comment: Never heard of this. I see its caching layer is not available till Winter 16' is this still an option I can try right now?

Comment: Alternatively, [JSON.deserializeUntyped](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm#apex_System_Json_deserializeUntyped)? You won't get to convert it back directly into a Reports.ReportResults object, but at least you'd have a navigable map...

Comment: I see it in my setup, but for some reason, we don't have any space allocated (0MB/0MB). It may be that we need to talk to our account executive, but I thought that Session and Platform cache were free, while other types (there's a half dozen or so) are paid cache.

Comment: The platform cache documentation is definitely speaking my language but the `deserializeUntyped` seems like a quicker solution. How would that look? Never used it before

Comment: I got the `Map<String, Object>` you're mentioned, but from here is there no way then to turn it back into a `Reports.ReportResults`?

Comment: Can Platform Cache store the data as a `Reports.ReportResults` so that nothing is ever converted? Looking into it more if that's the case this may be an option for us.

Comment: I need a little while to play with it, as Reports.ReportResults isn't something I use every day, but it should be pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by [@sfdcfox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2984/sfdcfox), I have the start of a solution using the [newly released Platform Cache](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_cache_namespace_overview.htm) using the Org Cache approach [described here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_platform_cache_org_examples.htm?search_text=cache.OrgPartition)

```
Reports.ReportResults results = Reports.ReportManager.runReport(reportId);
Cache.OrgPartition orgPart = Cache.Org.getPartition('local.PartionName');

// Retrieve cache value from the partition
if (orgPart.contains('ReportKey')) {
    Reports.ReportResults cachedResults = (Reports.ReportResults)orgPart.get('ReportKey');
}
// Add cache value to the partition
orgPart.put('ReportKey', results);
```

**NOTE**: *ReportKey must be alphanumeric*

The first time I ran this script I was happy to report that the results were stored as expected. Then, when I ran it the second time, after swaping the cast type from `String` to `Reports.ReportResults` the get() method worked as expected and I GOT MY RESULTS!

Kudos to sfdcfox for again being on point, and for opening my eyes to an option I didn't even realize was available.